# Swift Launch Screen Remove

Tags: ios, swift, launch-screen

I am completely naive in **iOS application development** and it is the first time I am using XCode for an iOS application development.

I am using **Swift** for the purpose and I do not want a launch screen for my app.

So, is it possible to eliminate the launch screen, if yes then how and if not then how to control or add actions to the launch screen ?